# How do I install tesseract-ocr if I get this error

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I found out about `pytesseract` and OCR with python so I wanted to try it out and for it to work I need to install tesseract-ocr using pip install on windows but it doesn't work and I get an error. I already have `pytesseract` and `tesseract` installed but not `tesseract-ocr`.

I tried downloading tesseract-ocr from pycharm as well but it doesn't work, I also downloaded Leptonica but it didn't fix anything.
So how do I fix this?

Here is the error :

```
Installing collected packages: tesseract-ocr
  Running setup.py install for tesseract-ocr ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6mlxue4n\\tesseract-ocr\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1s62w6u0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
    file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
    running build_ext
    building 'tesseract_ocr' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6mlxue4n\\tesseract-ocr\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1s62w6u0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6mlxue4n\tesseract-ocr\
```

Comment: Follow this https://emop.tamu.edu/Installing-Tesseract-Windows8 or https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-Tesseract-OCR-on-windows-10

Comment: If you already have VB installed try to modify it otherwise install VB. https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.2_standalone:_Build_Tools_for_Visual_Studio_2019_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.2C_ARM64.29

Answer (score 0):

download the ms visual installer. once downloaded, navigate to individual components then select 'Windows 10/11 SDK (based on your version of windows)', 'C++ 2022 redistributable update', and 'C++/CLI support for v143 build tools (latest)'. then click modify on the bottom right corner.